pre-commit bash script not found even though it exists for .githooks
I'm really confused on this.
The file clearly exists and has executable mode on. this is not woking on my VM running fedora. but runs fine on windows host with git-bash
I did set -x to see but i see same error
ajeet@fedora /home/ajeet/Repo/prov/xyz-service-app (dummy *%)$ git commit -am "Test"
+ git commit -am Test
fatal: cannot exec '.githooks/pre-commit': No such file or directory

The file is there for sure.
ajeet@fedora /home/ajeet/Repo/prov/xyz-service-app (dummy *%)$ cd .githooks/
ajeet@fedora /home/ajeet/Repo/prov/xyz-service-app/.githooks (dummy *%)$ ll
total 12
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 ajeet ajeet  975 Jun 18 15:37 pre-commit
-rwxr--r--. 1 ajeet ajeet 1664 Jun 18 15:26 SetupGitHooks.class
-rwxr--r--. 1 ajeet ajeet 1357 Jun 18 15:26 SetupGitHooks.java
ajeet@fedora /home/ajeet/Repo/prov/xyz-service-app/.githooks (dummy *%)$ ./pre-commit 
bash: ./pre-commit: cannot execute: required file not found
ajeet@fedora /home/ajeet/Repo/prov/xyz-service-app/.githooks (dummy *%)$


set -x for bash debugging output, check that first then come back if still got issues. Please, don't post screenshots, just copy/paste is all that's required

with set -x, I see the No such file or directory as the first line.  Will update the post

The file exists, but what's its shebang? If you saved it with DOS newlines and it starts with #!/bin/sh, for example, then it's really looking for $'/bin/sh\r', with a carriage return on the end of the file; that, of course, doesn't exist, so you get an error because the interpreter wasn't found.

(It's also possible your script had a BOM on it -- that's a Windows thing principally; I added a second duplicate with an answer explicitly covering that case).

@Charles Duffy the shebang was #!/bin/bash I undeleted this question only for your comment. massive.

Found some useful hint here: https://askubuntu.com/a/133460/1101876
created a fresh file and pasted the same content in that. now it works
dos2unix pre-commit
is the solution

You could probably have just run dos2unix against it, assuming it's a script. (If it were an executable, then you'd want to run ldd against it, see which linker and libraries it's trying to use, and address whichever one of those is missing).

Regardless -- please try to extend the question/answer pair with enough debugging details to let folks determine when this answer is going to be applicable. (It's certainly not applicable to all possible problems having the symptom described! The most likely one would make the question duplicative of Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?, but there's enough lack of clarity to make that assessment a guess rather than a certainty).
